# How to recieve and read data through UART from microcontroller using VB

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, uart

I will be posting my code for whatever I have done till now.

I'm sending data to microcontroller, but now I've to check other way and want to receive data.

I have written code which itself acts as `UART`. I am using readexisting and able to read some characters which is unrelevent, but  I'm not able to read required data.

```
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class Settings

    Dim myComPort As New SerialPort

    ' Call a routine to write a command to turn on an LED and read the response. 

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        SendCommand("7")

    End Sub

    ' Call a routint write a command to turn on an LED and read the response. 

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SendCommand("A")
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        SendCommand("C")

    End Sub
    Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

        myComPort.BaudRate = CInt(cmbBitRate.SelectedItem)
        TextBox4.Text = myComPort.BaudRate

    End Sub

    ' If myComPort is open, finish transmitting. 
    ' Exiting the Using block closes the port and releases its resources. 

    Sub CloseComPort()

        Try

            Using myComPort

                If (Not (myComPort Is Nothing)) Then

                    ' The COM port exists. 

                    If myComPort.IsOpen Then

                        ' Wait for the transmit buffer to empty. 

                        Do While (myComPort.BytesToWrite > 0)
                        Loop

                    End If
                End If

            End Using

        Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException

            ' The port may have been removed. Ignore. 

        End Try

    End Sub


    ' Set the BaudRate property of myComPort to match the bit rate selected in the combo box. 

    Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbBitRate.SelectedIndexChanged

        myComPort.BaudRate = CInt(cmbBitRate.SelectedItem)
        'TextBox2.Text = ToString(myComPort.BaudRate)


    End Sub


    ' If the previously selected COM port is open, close it. 
    ' Set the PortName property of myComPort to match the port selected in the combo box. 
    ' Call a routine to open the port. 

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbPorts.SelectedIndexChanged

        CloseComPort()
        myComPort.BaudRate = CInt(cmbBitRate.SelectedItem)
        ' myComPort.BaudRate = 500
        'TextBox2.Text = myComPort.BaudRate

        OpenComPort()
    End Sub


    ' Call a routine to close the COM port. 


    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

        CloseComPort()

    End Sub


    ' Call routines to initalize the form and open the selected COM port. 

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        InitializeForm()
        OpenComPort()
        AddHandler myComPort.DataReceived, AddressOf DataReceivedeventHandler

    End Sub


    ' Set up the form and select a default port and bit rate. 

    Sub InitializeForm()

        Dim bitRates(9) As Integer
        Dim nameArray() As String

        ' Find the COM ports on the system. 

        nameArray = SerialPort.GetPortNames
        Array.Sort(nameArray)

        ' Fill a combo box with the port names. 

        cmbPorts.DataSource = nameArray


        cmbPorts.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList

        ' Select a default port. 

        'cmbPorts.SelectedIndex = 1

        'Bit rates to select from. 

        bitRates(0) = 300
        bitRates(1) = 600
        bitRates(2) = 1200
        bitRates(3) = 2400
        bitRates(4) = 9600
        bitRates(5) = 14400
        bitRates(6) = 19200
        bitRates(7) = 38400
        bitRates(8) = 57600
        bitRates(9) = 115200



        'Place the bit rates in a combo box. 

        cmbBitRate.DataSource = bitRates
        cmbBitRate.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList


        ' Select a default bit rate. 
        ' If (Not (cmbBitRate Is Nothing)) Then
        'CloseComPort()
        'End If

    End Sub


    ' Set port parameters and open the COM port  
    ' associated with the SerialPort object myComPort. 


    Sub OpenComPort()

        Try
            ' Get the selected COM port's name from the combo box. 

            If Not myComPort.IsOpen Then
                myComPort.PortName = cmbPorts.SelectedItem.ToString

                ' Get the selected bit rate from the combo box. 

                If cmbBitRate.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
                    myComPort.BaudRate = CInt(cmbBitRate.SelectedItem)
                    TextBox4.Text = myComPort.BaudRate
                End If
                'myComPort.BaudRate = CInt(cmbBitRate.SelectedItem)

                ' Set other port parameters. 

                myComPort.Parity = Parity.None
                myComPort.DataBits = 8
                myComPort.StopBits = StopBits.One
                myComPort.Handshake = Handshake.None

                myComPort.ReadTimeout = 3000
                myComPort.WriteTimeout = 5000

                ' Open the port. 

                myComPort.Open()

            End If

        Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        Catch ex As System.IO.IOException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        End Try
    End Sub

    ' Write a command to the SerialPort object and read the response. 

    ''' <param name= "command"> The command to send. </param> 

    Private Sub SendCommand(ByVal command As String)

        ' Dim response As String

        Try

            'TextBox1.BackColor = Color.MediumPurple
            myComPort.Write(command)
            'myComPort.ReadTimeout = 1000
            ' While myComPort.ReadLine = 0


            ' End While
            'If myComPort.IsOpen Then
            'myComPort.ReadLine()
            'End If
            'TextBox6.Text = myComPort.ReadLine


            Select Case command

                Case "A"

                    ' TextBox6.Text = myComPort.
                    TextBox1.Text = "Green LED is on"
                    TextBox1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen


                Case "7"

                    TextBox1.Text = " Red LED is ON"
                    TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Red
                    'TextBox6.Text = myComPort.ReadLine



                Case "C"

                    TextBox1.Text = " Both LED's are ON"
                    TextBox1.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue
                    'TextBox6.Text = myComPort.ReadLine


                Case Else

            End Select

        Catch ex As TimeoutException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        End Try
    End Sub
    Public Sub DataReceivedeventHandler(
                           ByVal sender As Object,
                           ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
        Dim sp As SerialPort = CType(sender, SerialPort)
        Dim indata As String = sp.ReadExisting()
        ' Dim jndata As String = sp.ReadChar
        MsgBox(indata)
        'TextBox6.Text = CStr(vbMsgBoxRtlReading)
       ' MsgBox(jndata)
        ' Console.WriteLine("Data Received:")
        Console.Write(indata)

        '  ArgumentException.Equals(indata)
    End Sub


    Public Sub TextBox6_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox6.TextChanged

    End Sub

    'Private Sub DataReceivedEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    '    Throw New NotImplementedException
    'End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Is your Controller sending data??

Comment: Yes ..it is..I have programmed it .Now only one way communication is happening I want in two ways.I'm recieving but it is irrevelent data.I think data recieved should be converted to readable. But i have no idea since i'm new to .net.

Comment: hi got it .There was problem in microcontroller code. I had not enabled reciever interrupt.I am able to recieve data.

Comment: Glad you did!! Wait... You are sending data FROM microcontroller and you were not able to receive it on PC... So, How "Reciever Interrupt" comes in picture?

Comment: Yes I am using MSP430 using timers.. receiver and transmit interrupt has to be enabled which I missed to enable interrupt..

Comment: But now I have one more problem.I am receiving data and able to display through message box but once i'm getting blank box and in next box i'm able display.. wait i'l show that piece of code

Comment: Private SerialDataReceivedEventHandler1 _
    As New SerialDataReceivedEventHandler _
    (AddressOf DataReceived)
   Friend Sub DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
        Try
            Dim newReceivedData As String
            ' Get data from the COM port.
            newReceivedData = CStr(myComPort.ReadExisting)
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(newReceivedData) Then
                MsgBox(newReceivedData)
            End If

Comment: @ Swanand Purankar .I had written reciever function in microcontroller code and had commented it by mistake.In that function I had enabled interrupt.Hope I'm clear